# remover ".php" usando .htacces em subdominio

Tags: php, htaccess, subdomínio

Estou com um problema ao tentar utilizar a página sem precisar digitar a extensão.
Ex: http://sub.dominio.com/pagina.php para http://sub.dominio.com/pagina

Já tentei achar em outros sites sobre o mesmo mas nenhum esta funcionando no subdominio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º Verifique se o mod_rewrite está ligado.

2º Crie o arquivo .htaccess com o seguinte conteúdo

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

> Lembre-se de colocar o arquivo na raiz do sub-domínio.